# How do I sort the csv file alphabetically and how to not show the "hidden" ones in the console with my code

Tags: c#, csv, sorting

I need to sort my csv file alphabetically and not show the ones that it says "hidden" for (aka. client 4 and client 5) this is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadCSFVFile();
        Console.WriteLine();

    }

static void ReadCSFVFile()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Navigation.txt");
                  
        var list = new List<Company>();
        
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {              
            var values = line.Split(';' );
            var company = new Company() { ID = values[0], MenuName = values[1], ParentID = values[2], IsHidden = values[3], LinkURL = values[4] };
            list.Add(company);
               
         
        }

        list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.ID}\t {x.MenuName}\t {x.ParentID}\t {x.IsHidden}\t {x.LinkURL}"));
        
    }

 public class Company 
    {  
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get; set; }
        public string ParentID { get; set; }
        public string IsHidden { get; set; }
        public string LinkURL { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the csv file:

- ID;MenuName;ParentID;isHidden;LinkURL
- 1;Company;NULL;False;    /company
- 2;About Us;1;False;  /company/aboutus
- 3;Mission;1;False;  /company/mission
- 4;Team;2;False;  /company/aboutus/team
- 5;Client 2;10;False;  /references/client2
- 6;Client 1;10;False;  /references/client1
- 7;Client 4;10;True;  /references/client4
- 8;Client 5;10;True;  /references/client5
- 10;References;NULL;False;  /references

Comment: Look into LINQ: OrderBy() and Where(). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should achieve this for you. I've commented the parts I've added to  help out.

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.MenuName) // Order alphabetically based on MenuName
    .Where(x => x.IsHidden != "True") // Filter only for non-hidden items
    .ToList().ForEach(
    x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.ID}\t {x.MenuName}\t {x.ParentID}\t{x.IsHidden}\t {x.LinkURL}"));
```

Comment: When I try this it says that "operator ! cannot be applied to 'string'"

Comment: Sorry didnt notice it was a string, ive updated the code